# Is there a method in PHP to get the default email of a user?

Tags: php, mailto

Is there a PHP method to fetch the default email of a user? same effect if you would use mailto:

Example scenario:

If you use `mailto:some@email.com` to open mail client it would automatically fill in the "From" field of the form with the user's email.

I want to do the same effect to my PHP form. I want to fill in with the default email address with the user email. so when they press contact, it would automatically fill in the email field with the users default email.

Is possible?

Note: should also be compatible with mobile phone, like iPhone and Android.

Thanks!

Comment: This would be a massive security problem if it were possible.

Comment: Default email is client OS side data. You cant get it using php

Comment: ok thanks for confirming, I guess there's no sense of this question. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your PHP script cannot track your clients (users) and see what their email addresses are.

The `mailto:` links only open the default mail client on the user's machine and fills in the proper details (taken from your `mailto:` link).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not possible way of doing that.